# How to convert digit month to the full name of month in C# console

Tags: c#, console

I want to convert digit month that is inputed by User to the name of month. I find it easily to use if else condition, but is there any function I can use without using condition? It's take me to write alot of code.
Note : Just month!

```
int month = 0;
bool TempResult = false;
Console.Write("Month: ");
TempResult = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Month);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two reasonably simple options:

- Construct a date using that number as the month, and then format it with a custom format, e.g.

  ```
  DateTime date = new DateTime(2000, month, 1);
  string monthName = date.ToString("MMMM");
  ```
- Use [`DateTimeFormatInfo.MonthNames`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthnames)

  ```
  DateTimeFormatInfo info = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat; 
  // The array is 0-based, e.g. MonthNames[0] is for January
  string monthName = info.MonthNames[month - 1];
  ```

Both of these will take the name from the current culture; in either case you can specify a different `CultureInfo` if you want. (In the first case, use it as a second argument to `ToString`.)

Comment: I got it! Thank you, so can you tell me more about date formart in ToString? Or you can give me a reference link.

Comment: @RathpanhaSarun: Sure, just search for "custom date format msdn" and you'll get to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx